# VBA Trouble going back and activating original workbook

Tags: vba, excel

VBA noob. Script to search input data, match criteria, go into existing spreadsheet, copy to latest row, and then go back to original input workbook to repeat.

I can get everything working with absolute paths (ie "Book1.csv") but I will have to replace these every time I run the macro with a new input data workbook. Pretty sure I have the dim/set part figured out but every time I call the Windows().Activate I always get subscript out of range. Code:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

' Search Title column (B) for match
     Cells.Find(What:="A154L-T031-#1590", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

' Select date and copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:Q1").Copy

' Activate and select correct sheet in NCRP spreadsheet and then select row after latest data
Windows("Approach_North.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("T031").Activate
Range("T1048576").End(xlUp).Select

' Select row below it and paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' To repeat have to go back to the original data sheet
Windows(wb1).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

The debugger lands on Windows(wb1).Activate.

Any help what doing wrong?

Comment: maybe `Windows(wb1.name).Activate`

Comment: What error message are you getting when it crashes?  Have you printed out the value of `wb1` in the immediate pane?

Comment: @Jeeped where .name is the sheetname? I assumed with only one sheet it would default to it.

Comment: @MarkStewart error line 9, subscript out of range error message. I don't know how to print the value of wb1 since its a dim as a Workbook. I tried MsgBox but as I thought it's an unacceptable object type. How can I parse the wb1 Workbook object to get a string and then how to print() it?

Comment: wb1 is a workbook object (Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook). Windows(nnn).Activate is looking for a string, not a workbook object so I suggested the workbook name. Why Window at all? Why not wb1.activate? For that matter, why activate at all?

Comment: @Jeeped Total noob, reading everywhere it posted to avoid workbook activate but I just don't know VBA/couldn't figure how to store/call and do what I wanted to do in memory. Didn't realize it was a string also, so assigning a string variable to the workbook name works in my cumbersome code right now. If I can figure out how to set that string to the current workbook name I think I'd be set, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No need for select/activate:

```
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Cells.Find(What:="A154L-T031-#1590", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then

       f.Copy Workbooks("Approach_North.xlsx").Worksheets("T031").Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       f.Bold = True

    End If
```

Comment: This works! Except just selecting that original title cell, not the data next to it - the part:     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:Q1").Copy    where do I fit this part in?

Comment: The following is 'bold'ing both source and destination, where I just wanted the source bolded (to show it has been dealt with) - any ideas?

    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Cells.Find(What:="A154L-T031-#1590", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:Q1")

    If Not f Is Nothing Then

       f.Copy Workbooks("Approach_North.xlsx").Worksheets("T031").Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       f.Font.Bold = True

    End If

Comment: Figured it out - put the bolding after the If - duh!

Comment: If you need to post a block of code, you can edit your question to add it there